# Expressing "For every positive integer $a$, there exists an integer $b$ with $|b| < a$ such that $|bx| < a$ for every real number $x$" symbolically

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, quantifiers

I would like to express

> For every positive integer $a$, there exists an integer $b$ with $|b| < a$ such that $|bx| < a$ for every real number $x$

symbolically. My attempt:

> For every positive integer $a$

This tells us that $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$.

> there exists an integer $b$

This tells us that $\exists b \in \mathbb{Z}$

> with $|b| < a$

This tells us that $P(a,b) : |b| < a$.

> such that $|bx| < a$ for every real number $x$

This tells us that $Q(a,b,x) : |bx| < a$ and $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, Q(a,b,x)$.

Now putting it all together, I think we would have:

> $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists b \in \mathbb{Z}, P(a,b) \implies \forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists b \in \mathbb{Z},\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, Q(a,b,x).$

Alternatively, it could also be

> $\forall a \in \mathbb{Z}^+, \exists b \in \mathbb{Z},\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, P(a,b) \implies Q(a,b,x)$

It could also be the case that neither of them are correct I suppose. Please let me know which you think is the most correct in this case, and why. Thank you!

Comment: $\forall a \exists b \ [|b|<a \land \forall x (|bx|<a)]$

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Hmm, thanks. What about what I wrote?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on Math SE!

What you proposed is quite good. Nevertheless, let's get back on it, identify then correct the mistakes.
(NB : There different solutions that can be accepted for such question, I'm going to try the one that is best understandable.)

> For every positive integer $a$

You said $\forall a\in\mathbb{Z}_+$. But $\mathbb{Z_+}$ has a "name", it is $\mathbb{N}$. So, let's write: $$\forall a\in\mathbb{N}$$

> There exists an integer $b$

I will use this one with the following one and combine them:

> There exists an integer $b$ with $\vert b\vert < a$.

Then, if $b\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $\vert b\vert < a$, we necessarily have $b\in]\!]-a,a[\![$. So, we can write it as: $$\exists b\in]\!]-a,a[\![$$

> such as for every real number $x$, $\vert bx\vert<a$

You got it : $$\forall x\in\mathbb{R}\, (\vert bx\vert<a)$$

Now, let's put the pieces back together:
$$\forall a\in\mathbb{N}\exists b\in]\!]-a,a[\![ (\forall x\in\mathbb{R}, \vert bx\vert<a)$$

If you have any questions, do not hesitate.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I do have a question: why did you choose to put $b \in (-a,a)$? Shouldn't it be a conjunction instead of an element of a set?

Comment: Check again, I didn’t include $a$ in the interval as the inequality is strict. It is not mandatory as a has already been introduced. So we can use the definition of the modulus inferior to a certain positive value.

Comment: Sorry, you're right it's strict, but the question remains the same. Is it wrong to make it a conjunction, instead of letting $b$ be an element of that interval?

Comment: Indeed it is not, but it’ll be longer and more complicated to write. It is at your discretion, I don’t think it’d be incorrect.